# CAShapeLayer rounding corners impacts performance

Tags: ios, performance, uicollectionview, rounded-corners, cashapelayer

I have a UICollectionView (iPad) that has jarry scrolling.Each cell has a white rectangle UIView (with all rounded corners) that has another UIImageView in front of it with only top two corners rounded. See this link below for how this cell looks - [i.stack.imgur.com/Ptlig.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptlig.png)

Here's the code for the UICollectionViewCell

```
    UIView * bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, (self.contentView.frame.size.width - 10), (self.contentView.frame.size.width - 10)*IMAGE_RATIO + 43.5)];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    bgView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    bgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 179/255.0 green:181/255.0 blue:184/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    bgView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    bgView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    bgView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    [self.contentView addSubview:bgView];

    self.parablePost = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, (self.contentView.frame.size.width - 10), (self.contentView.frame.size.width-10)*IMAGE_RATIO)];
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.parablePost.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.parablePost.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    self.parablePost.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.parablePost];
```

When this line "*self.parablePost.layer.mask = maskLayer*" is commented, scrolling is smooth. So the CAShapeLayer is causing performance issues. I tried rasterize and hand drawing instead of using UIBezierPath but it does not improve the experience.

Is there a faster way to round two corners of UIImageView?

**EDIT:**

I finally added static images to simulate rounded corners on the top two corners of the UIImageView that gave me the same look without the scroll jitter. Surprised that CAShapeLayer is a performance drain.

Comment: masks are expensive--they are CPU rendered. try to think of another way to get the look you want.

Comment: Maybe a better idea is to use normal corner rounding but then hide the bottom rounded corners behind the white info portion of your cell.

Comment: Can't you just turn on rounded corners for your entire cell and not worry about your sublayers having rounded corners?

Comment: @nielsbot that would need cliptobounds on bgView to curve the UIImageView which is also slow.

Comment: I thought using round corners is a special fast path? You could profile the performance to make sure...

Answer (score 0):

masks are expensive... (they might even be rendered in software). try to think of another way to get the look you want. for example, pre-render things to an image...

Comment: Good comment. Since this is not a static image to pre-render, is there any way to pre-render an image on demand?

Comment: Sure--you can use a CGBitmapContext, but that may not be faster. I was asking if your background or pieces in your cell could be images (rendered ahead of time or rendered once in software)